# How to derive this simple geometric relationship using cosine law?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given the above figure, I need to show that

$$cos(a_2) = \frac{x_1^2 + y_1^2 - L_1^2 - L_2^2}{2L_1L_2} $$

Where $L_1, L_2$ are the length of the red lines respectively, and $a_1, a_2$ are the angles

How to show this holds by using cosine law?

Can anyone show me how this can be done?

Comment: Connect the point $(x_1,y_1)$ to the origin. The length of the new segment is $\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}$. Apply the Law of Cosines to the triangle formed by that segment and the two red segments (using the angle between the two red segments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since
$$a_{2}=\pi-\angle BAO\Longrightarrow \cos{a_{2}}=-\cos{\angle BAO}$$
and sinc $B(x_{1},y_{1})$,then we have
$$|OB|^2=x^2_{1}+y^2_{1}$$
use cosine
$$|OB|^2=|OA|^2+|AB|^2-2|OA|\cdot|AB|\cdot\cos{(\angle OAB)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow x^2_{1}+y^2_{1}=L^2_{1}+L^2_{2}+2L_{1}\cdot L_{2}\cos{a_{2}}$$
so
$$\cos{a_{2}}=\dfrac{x^2_{1}+y^2_{1}-L^2_{1}-L^2_{2}}{2L_{1}L_{2}}$$[image]

Comment: So cos(a) = -cos($\pi$-a), aha good to know